# Storing and Accessing a 2D Array in a Struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, multidimensional-array

I am trying to code a program in C that generates a spiral based on user input and prints it to the console. I cannot figure out how to access the 2D array "data" that I defined in the struct "Spiral". How do I fix the "warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type" error?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Spiral {
    int size;
    int **data;
} Spiral;

Spiral generateSpiral(int size);
void printSpiral(Spiral spiral);
static int rotate();

int main() {
    int size;
    scanf("%d", &size);
    Spiral spiral = generateSpiral(size);
    printSpiral(spiral);
    return 0;
}

Spiral generateSpiral(int size) {
    int data[size][size];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            data[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        data[0][i] = 1;
    }

    int currX = 0;
    int currY = size - 1;

    for (i = size - 1; i > 0; i -= 2) {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            int k;
            switch (rotate()) {
                case 0:
                    for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                        data[++currX][currY] = 1;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    for (k = i; k > 0; k--) {
                        data[currX][--currY] = 1;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    for (k = i; k > 0; k--) {
                        data[--currX][currY] = 1;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                        data[currX][++currY] = 1;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    Spiral spiral;
    spiral.size = size;
    spiral.data = data;
    return spiral;
}

void printSpiral(Spiral spiral) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < spiral.size; i++) {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < spiral.size; j++) {
            switch (spiral.data[i][j]) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("#");
                    break;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

static int rotate() {
    static int val = 0;
    int tmp = val;
    val++;
    if (val > 3)
        val = 0;
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: type of `data`(int data[size][size];) is not `int **`. also it can not be used outside a function pointer to an automatic local variables.

Comment: Wait, this compiles `int data[size][size];` when `size` is not const? Anyways `int data[][]` is a different type than `int** data`

Comment: @luk32 `int data[size][size]` is a normal [variable-length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: If `spiral.data = data;` didn't flag a compiler warning, jam up your warning level, because its wrong. They're not the same types, not that it matters, as you're saving a local automatic address then expecting it to be valid caller-side after the function returns and the `data` array is no longer valid.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think that is precisely the line that gives the warning/error, as there is clearly a type mismatch there. I think if it was solved, next thing would be assigning a local variable that goes out of scope. It probably stopped at the 1st thing that was wrong.

Comment: @luk32 I hope it is indeed. The OP didn't specify which line was the specific warning.

Comment: @WhozCraig You are right, that is the line that gives the warning. Sorry for not including that in the original post.

Answer (score 7):

In the `generateSpiral` function you make the structures pointer point to the local variable `data`, but when the function returns `data` goes out of scope so the pointer now points to unallocated memory leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

But that's not your only problem: A second problem is that a pointer to a pointer is *not* the same as an array of arrays, the memory layout is different.

---

For the last part, lets check an example. Lets say we have the following declaration

```
int a[2][2];
```

In memory it will look something like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| a[0][0] | a[0][1] | a[1][0] | a[1][1] |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

In other words, all data is contiguous.

If you, on the other hand have a declaration like

```
int **p;
```

and allocate data for it correctly, it will look something like

```
+------+------+-----+
| p[0] | p[1] | ... |
+------+------+-----+
  |      |      |
  |      |      v
  |      |      ...
  |      v
  |      +---------+---------+-----+
  |      | p[1][0] | p[1][1] | ... |
  |      +---------+---------+-----+
  v
  +---------+---------+-----+
  | p[0][0] | p[0][1] | ... |
  +---------+---------+-----+
```

The memory is no longer contiguous. There is no longer any maximum size, a pointer points to a contiguous area of memory, but there is no way of knowing how big that area is. You have to keep track of it yourself.

---

The simple solution to both the problems is to use only pointer to pointer, and then allocate dynamically of the heap:

```
int **data;

// First allocate memory for `size` number of pointers
// I.e. we allocate an "array" of pointers
data = malloc(size * sizeof(int *));

// Then allocate each entry in the above allocated "array"
// I.e. make each pointer in the "array" point to an "array" of `int`
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    data[i] = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

Now the local variable `data` can be used directly to assign to `spiral.data`.

But there is a catch: In Java you don't have to free memory you allocate, it's handled automatically. In C it's not handled automatically, you have to manually free the memory you allocate or you will have a *memory leak*.

Freeing the memory can be done like

```
// First free all the "sub-arrays"
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    free(spiral.data[i]);

// Then free the top-level "array"
free(spiral.data);
```

---

Regarding pointers, a pointer can point to any memory address, and there is really no safety or checking that it points to a valid location. Also, C does not do deep copying of values and structures, if you have a pointer and make it point somewhere, then the compiler or runtime system doesn't make a copy.

And about scoping, Java has local variables as well, and just like in C when a function returns those go out of scope. The difference between Java and C, is that if you return a reference to a local object, then Java keeps track of that and keep the object in memory as long as there are references to the object. C doesn't have references, a pointer is just an integer whose value is an address in memory, and the data pointed to have no idea that there are pointers to it or how many.

Comment: How do I fix it? I'm coming from Java, trying to learn C, and don't entirely understand scope and pointers in C.

Comment: Generally, you want to declare the instance of `Spiral` in main and pass a pointer to `generateSpiral`, e.g. `Spiral generateSpiral(Spiral *sp, int size)`, you can then operate on it directly or declare the function as `Spiral *generateSpiral` and return a pointer.

Comment: @Daniel Updated my answer with the reason an array of arrays is not the same as a pointer to a pointer. Also added a possible solution to both problems.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude dude I am not sure you ensured contigious allocation with the implementation you provided...

Comment: @codemonkey No it's not, it's a *jagged array*, and not contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to a mismatch between the int and the unsigned int returned by the vectors size function. Change your int i , j to type size_t so they are also an unsigned integer like the size of the vectors. This is why you are getting the warning