# How to manipulate an array of structure containing 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

Using **C++**, I am implementing an **array** of structure *HiddenLayer* defined as

```
    struct HiddenLayer
    {
        int prev;     ///Number of Rows in node
        int next;     ///Number of Columns in node

        float **node; ///2D array pointer
    };
```

The array of structure is initialized in the main routine and **node** is the pointer to the 2D array inside the structure. I am initializing this array as

```
    int main()
    {
        struct HiddenLayer HLayer[1]; 

        HLayer[0].prev = 1;  //Num of rows
        HLayer[0].next = 3;  //num of col

        HLayer[0].node = (float *) malloc((HLayer[0].prev) * sizeof(float *));  
 
        for(int i=0;i<HLayer[0].prev;i++)
            HLayer[0].node[i] = malloc(HLayer[0].next * sizeof(float));

    
        return 0;
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:22:73: error: cannot convert ‘float*’ to ‘float**’ in assignment
     HLayer[0].node = (float *) malloc((HLayer[0].prev) * sizeof(float *));  
                                                                         ^

>main.cpp:25:35: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘float*’ [-fpermissive]
         HLayer[0].node[i] = malloc(HLayer[0].next * sizeof(float));
```

I followed the answers given [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454022/storing-and-accessing-a-2d-array-in-a-struct) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088025/malloc-invalid-conversion-from-void-to-double)

What wrong am I doing?

Comment: So this is not [tag:c], right?

Comment: `(float *) malloc` should at least be `(float **) malloc`

Comment: 1. You are trying to affect a `float *` to a `float **`.
2. You are not casting to the correct type.

Comment: … and your other `malloc` should cast to `(float *)` - simples!

Comment: Sorry. Was thrown off by the use of malloc.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/184540/1216776

Comment: You are not writing C++ code and the answers you are following are not talking about C++. They are talking about C. These two are different languages in which very different programming styles are considered good and which behave differently. For example using the pointer returned by `malloc` without a placement-new following it is technically undefined behavior in C++ and in C++ you would use `std::vector` instead of manual memory allocation.  Please re-evaluate whether you *really* want to ask about C++.

Comment: @walnut, I intend to avoid vectors, due to the limitations of my application. So, yeah, anything else is fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages are self-explanatory: you mixed up the types.

```
HLayer[0].node = (float *) malloc((HLayer[0].prev) * sizeof(float *));
```

should be

```
HLayer[0].node = (float **) malloc((HLayer[0].prev) * sizeof(float *));
```

and

```
HLayer[0].node[i] = malloc(HLayer[0].next * sizeof(float));
```

should be

```
HLayer[0].node[i] = (float *) malloc(HLayer[0].next * sizeof(float));
```

But that said, why'd you want to use `malloc()` and family in C++?

Comment: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) Isn't this true for C++ ? And why not `new` instead of `malloc`

Comment: @TruthSeeker (1) No. (2) That's the same as the last line in my answer.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, thnks for the answer! I am bound to avoid C++ features like new and STL containers.

Comment: But how should I add and manipulate data to this array? @SouravGhosh

Comment: @PeDro You cannot reliably use dynamic memory allocation in C++ without `new` or the standard library. `malloc` without `new` causes undefined behavior technically always and for sure if the types used are non-trivial. Having a restriction on using `new`, but allowing `malloc`, makes no sense in C++.